# Deciphering AD7730 outputs

Tags: spi, adc, oscillator-clock

I am currently working with a [AD7730 chip](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7730_7730l.pdf) for analog-digital conversion. The chip is programmable, and I have been pulling code from GitHub as well as other links.

I am unfamiliar with SPI (the communication protocol it uses), which I believe is most of the problem. I have been using the code pulled from [this library](https://github.com/gmckern/AD7730/tree/main/examples) on GitHub as well as its wiring diagram.

[image: Wiring diagram]

The wiring diagram above is nearly identical to my wiring with the only exception that the load cell and amplifier have been replaced with a voltage source. Here is the header file for the code:

```cpp
#ifndef AD7730_h
#define AD7730_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Math.h"

class AD7730 {
    public:
        AD7730(int resetPin, int readyPin, int chipSelect);
        void reset(); // resets the AD7730 chip. Equivalent to a power down power up.
        void internalCalibrate(); // performs internal zero and full scale calibrations of the chip
        void systemZeroCalibrate(); // performs system zero scale calibration only of the system (sets the intercept to zero in the linear transfer function)
        void systemFullCalibrate(); // performs full scale calibration of the system.
        void waitForReady(); // pause until ready pin goes low
        void offsetDAC(float offset); // Sets the DAC tare offset value. Allowed range is -40 to 40 (mV) in increments of 2.5 mV
        void range(int range); // Sets the voltage range (gain) of the chip. Allowed values are 10, 20, 40, 80. 10mv range is most sensitive
        void vRef(float volts); // Sets the value of the high reference voltage. Allowed values are 2.5, 5 volts
        void channel(int chan); // Sets the input channel (1 or 2)
        void filter(int avg); // Sets the number of samples to be averaged by the smoothing filter. Default is 512. Max smoothing is 4095.
        void continuousConversionMode(); // places the chip in continuous conversion mode (but does not begin continuous reading)
        void unipolar(); // sets the chip in unipolar conversion mode
        void bipolar(); // sets the chip in bipolar conversion mode (default)
        unsigned long read(); // takes a single reading of the raw result from the AD7730 chip using the parameters set above.
        float readVoltage(); // takes a single voltage reading from the chip using the parameters set above and converts to a voltage.
    private:
        int _resetPin;
        int _readyPin;
        int _CS;
};

#endif
```

Here is the class file:

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "AD7730.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Math.h"

AD7730::AD7730(int resetPin, int readyPin, int chipSelect) {
    SPI.begin();
    SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);
    SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST); 
    SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV128);
    
    pinMode(resetPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(readyPin, INPUT);   
    pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MISO, INPUT);
    pinMode(MOSI, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(resetPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(chipSelect, HIGH);

    _resetPin = resetPin;
    _readyPin = readyPin;
    _CS = chipSelect;
}


void AD7730::reset() {
    // perform a hardware reset using the reset pin on the chip
    digitalWrite(_resetPin, LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(_resetPin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
}

void AD7730::internalCalibrate() {
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (2 byte register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
    
    byte1 = (byte1 & 0x1f) | (0x4 << 5); // update byte1 to write internal zero scale calibration to chip 

    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write updated second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);

    
    waitForReady(); // wait for internal zero scale calibration to complete
    
    byte1 = (byte1 & 0x1f) | (0x5 << 5); // update byte1 to write internal full scale calibration to chip 
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write updated second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
    
    waitForReady(); // wait for internal full scale calibration to complete
}

void AD7730::systemZeroCalibrate() {
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (2 byte register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
    
    byte1 = (byte1 & 0x1f) | (0x6 << 5); // update byte1 to write system zero scale calibration to chip 

    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write updated second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
    
    waitForReady(); // wait for system zero scale calibration to complete
}

void AD7730::systemFullCalibrate() {
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (2 byte register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
    
    byte1 = (byte1 & 0x1f) | (0x7 << 5); // update byte1 to write system zero scale calibration to chip 

    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write updated second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
    
    waitForReady(); // wait for system zero scale calibration to complete
}

void AD7730::waitForReady() {
    while(digitalRead(_readyPin)) {
        // keep waiting as long as ready pin remains HIGH
    }
}

void AD7730::offsetDAC(float offset) {
    int index = (int)(offset/2.5);
    int sign = 0;
    if (index < 0) {
        sign = 1;
        index *= -1;
    }
    int toSend = (sign << 5 | index); // format offset setting as byte to send to DAC register
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x04); // set next operation as single write to the DAC register
    SPI.transfer(toSend); // write data to DAC register
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

void AD7730::range(int range) {
    // format range setting is 2 bits to write to Mode register
    int bits;
    if (range <= 10) {
        bits = 0;
    } else if(range <= 20) {
        bits = 1;
    } else if(range <= 40) {
        bits = 2;
    } else {
        bits = 3;
    }
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (16 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0xff); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0xff); // read second byte
        
    byte2 = (0xcf & byte2) | (bits << 4); // replace current range bits with specified bits
    
    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write updated second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

void AD7730::vRef(float volts) {
    int bit;
    if(volts <= 2.5) {
        bit = 0;
    } else {
        bit = 1;
    }
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (16 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
        
    byte2 = (0x7f & byte2) | (bit << 7); // replace current range bits with specified bits
    
    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write updated second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

void AD7730::channel(int chan) {
    int bits;
    if (chan==1) {
        bits = 0;
    } else {
        bits = 1;
    }
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (16 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
        
    byte2 = (0xfc & byte2) | bits; // replace current channel bits with specified bits
    
    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write updated second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

void AD7730::filter(int avg) {
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x13); // set next operation as single read of Filter register (24 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
    int byte3 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read third byte
    
    // trim input parameter to 12 bits
    if (avg > 4095) {
        avg = 4095;
    }
    byte1 = avg >> 4; // fill byte1 with 8 most signicant bits of avg
    byte2 = (byte2 & 0xf) | avg << 8; // 4 least significant bits of avg spill over to byte2
    
    SPI.transfer(0x03); // set next operation as single write to Filter register
    SPI.transfer(byte1);
    SPI.transfer(byte2);
    SPI.transfer(byte3);
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

void AD7730::unipolar() {
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (16 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
        
    byte1 = (byte1 & 0xef) | 0x10; // configure unipolar conversion mode
    
    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

void AD7730::bipolar() {
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (16 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
        
    byte1 = (byte1 & 0xef); // configure bipolar conversion mode
    
    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

void AD7730::continuousConversionMode() {
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (16 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
        
    byte1 = (byte1 & 0x1f) | (0x01 << 5); // configure for continuous conversion mode
    
    SPI.transfer(0x02); // set next operation as single write to Mode register
    SPI.transfer(byte1); // write first byte
    SPI.transfer(byte2); // write second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
}

unsigned long AD7730::read() {
    // use when chip is in continuous conversion mode. This function takes a single reading so should be used in a loop.
    unsigned long result;
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x11); // set next operation as single read from Data register (24 bit register assuming the chip is used in 24 bit mode)
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
    
    waitForReady();
    
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
    int byte3 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
    
    result = byte1*256L*256L + byte2*256L + byte3;
    return result;
}

float AD7730::readVoltage() {
    digitalWrite(_CS, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(0x12); // set next operation as single read of Mode register (16 bit register)
    int byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read first byte
    int byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00); // read second byte
    digitalWrite(_CS, HIGH);
    
    unsigned long raw = read();
    int unipolar = (byte1 & 0xe0) >> 4; // mask out and shift polarity bit; 0 is bipolar, 1 is unipolar
    float mV;
    
    int range = (byte2 & 0xc0) >> 4; // mask out and shift range bits
    if (range == 0) {
        range = 10;
    } else if (range == 1) {
        range = 20;
    } else if (range == 2) {
        range = 40;
    } else {
        range = 80;
    }
    
    if (!unipolar) {
        mV = (float)range*((float)raw - (float)8388608)/(float)8388608;
        return mV;
    } else {
        mV = (float)range*(float)raw/(float)16777216;
        return mV;
    }
}
```

And here is the Arduino file that uses these two library files:

```cpp
#include <AD7730.h>

AD7730 adc(8,9,10); // create new instance with reset pin = 8, ready pin = 9, chip select pin = 10

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  adc.reset();          // reset the AD7730 chip
  adc.filter(512);      // set digital filter to 512 samples (This setting provides good filtering of 50 hz and 60 hz noise)
  adc.range(10);        // set voltage range to 10 millivolts (this sets the gain of the internal amplifier)
  adc.offsetDAC(0);     // use this function to correct for a wheatstone bridge circuit whose resistors aren't perfectly balanced
  adc.unipolar();       // set chip to unipolar mode
  adc.internalCalibrate();          // run internal calibration of chip before reading voltages
  adc.continuousConversionMode();   // place chip in continuous conversion mode
}

long result;            // declare variable to hold conversion results. Since the AD7730 is a 24bit ADC, the 16bit int data type will not work for this.

void loop() {
  result = adc.read();              // take a single conversion result from the chip
  Serial.println(result);           // print conversion result to the serial monitor
}
```

Running the above Arduino code produces output, albeit not correct. Putting the chip in its unipolar 10 mV range mode somehow outputs values of 40 mV when the analog signal is set to 0.00 mV. As the signal is increased or decreased in voltage, the output responds correspondingly but not according to the prescribed gain on the data sheet and sometimes it appears to change non-linearly. This happens with all voltage ranges and both the unipolar and bipolar modes: the output signals do not match the input signals to any degree.

I am wondering if this has to do with the conversion to mV at the bottom of the class file. Specifically,

```cpp
if (!unipolar) {
    mV = (float)range*((float)raw - (float)8388608)/(float)8388608;
    return mV;
} else {
    mV = (float)range*(float)raw/(float)16777216;
    return mV;
}
```

However, given that the ADC is reading with 24 bits, the 8388608 and 16777216 are accurate. Any help would be appreciated. I have been trying to troubleshoot this for about a month with no success.

Comment: The conversion seems legit. Did you change anything to the library or to the provided example? If not, you may want to collect more precise data and file an issue on the library's GitHub project.

Comment: Nothing has been changed from the library or the provided example. The only difference is that I am using a voltage supply for my ADC signal rather than some sort of load cell.

Comment: If the circuit is build out from breadboard, I would want to check if the crystal really oscillate, the tray capacitance plus the 22pf capacitors might not match the load capacitance of the crystal that you purchased.